# ios storyboard and uisegmented control relationships?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard

in `ios5` storyboards, `UITabController`s come pre-made with two relationships for the **First** tab and **Second** tab.

Is it possible to do relationships like this for a `UISegmentedControl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do this with storyboards, you would need to write the code to switch between views manually. `UITabBarController` is what manages the display of multiple `UIViewController` instances via the use of a `UITabBar`. There is no `UISegmentedControlController` class.

To accomplish this, you will need two views in your view controller, and switch between them on the `UISegmentedControl` `Value Changed` event.